# Chaining xpath axes

Tags: xpath

```
<tr class="even">
<td>101</td>
<td>NotProvisioned</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>
    <a href="procdef.jsf?id=101">Examine</a>
</td>
```

Hi folks, 
I've a number rows in a table. Using xpath I need to select the  element in the row where one of the td cells has the text value NotProvisioned and one of it's siblings has a

In firebug I tried the following,

```
$x("//td[[contains(text(),'NotProvisioned')]/following-sibling::* and child:a[contains(text(),'Examine']]")
```

I'm not sure if I'm even rooting on the right element. I should looking for an a element who's text is 'Examine' and whom has a preceding-ancester who's text is NonProvisioned but I can't figure out how to chain accordingly.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `//td[preceding-sibling::td[. = 'NotProvisioned']]/a[. = 'Examine']` you select `a` element children of `td` elements where the string value of the `a` element is `Examine` and the `td` has a preceding sibling `td` that has the string value `NotProvisioned`. If the `a` element can be a descendant you can use `//td[preceding-sibling::td[. = 'NotProvisioned']]//a[. = 'Examine']` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much Martin! That worked a charm! I had to swap out the . = for the longer hand. I guess that's something to do with the version of xpath in firebug? 

$x("//td[preceding-sibling::td[contains(text(), 'NotProvisionedSIMOrder')]]//a[ contains(text(), 'Examine')] ")